# Pandas: How to convert column of string objects representing categories to integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, categorical-data

For example, if I have a DataFrame `df`

```
    day     hour    price   booked
0   monday  7      12.0     True
1   monday  8      12.0     False
2   tuesday 7      13.0     True
3   sunday  8      13.0     False
4   monday  7      15.0     True
5   monday  8      13.0     False
6   tuesday 7      13.0     True
7   tuesday 8      15.0     False
```

where `df['day'].dtype` is `dtype('O')`, for example.

I would like to convert it to something like:

```
    day     hour    price   booked
0   1       7      12.0     1
1   1       8      12.0     0
2   2       7      13.0     1
3   3       8      13.0     0
4   1       7      15.0     1
5   1       8      13.0     0
6   2       7      13.0     1
7   2       8      15.0     0
```

The mapping to integers can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to encode the different values in the column as integers:

```
df['day'] = pd.factorize(df.day)[0]
```

This sets the 'day' column of the example DataFrame to the following:

```
>>> df
   day  hour  price booked
0    0     7     12   True
1    0     8     12  False
2    1     7     13   True
3    2     8     13  False
4    0     7     15   True
5    0     8     13  False
6    1     7     13   True
7    1     8     15  False
```

The 'day' column is of integer type:

```
>>> df.dtypes
day         int64
hour        int64
price     float64
booked       bool
```

Comment: Looks good. Can I do this operation on more than one column at a time?

Comment: I think you may have to apply the operation to each column individually since `factorize` only takes a 1D array as input.